# Button inside a ListViewItem doesn't invoke bounded Command

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, uwp, command

I use a ListView to show my list of datas.

I want to add a delete button to each of the ListViewItem so when user click the button the corresponding ListViewItem is removed from the list.

First I tried use the button's click event, and it works like a charm.

But after I  refactor that as a command , it no longer works.

I set several breakpoints in VS and make sure in ViewModel's Constructor the command is created.

However Clicking button doesn't execute RelayCommand.Execute() method.

I suspect the problem being something wrong with the Command's DataBinding
but I don't know how to investigate.

Thanks for any help

Here's my ListView and DataTemplate.

```
<ListView Name="SavedLoginDatas" ItemsSource="{x:Bind VM.SavedLogins,Mode=OneWay}" 
                      SelectionMode="None"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="False"

                      >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:LoginData">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Margin="15,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{x:Bind VM.CurrentLoginVM.Data.UserName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Height="48" Width="48" Content="Delete"
                Name="Delete"  Command="{Binding ElementName=VM,Path=RemoveSavedLoginCommand,Mode=OneWay}"  CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource = {RelativeSource Self}}"
                ></Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

here's my ViewModel

```
public class LoginVM : VMBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<LoginData> _savedLogins;


    public ObservableCollection<LoginData> SavedLogins
    {
        get { return _savedLogins; }
        set { _savedLogins = value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand<LoginData> RemoveSavedLoginCommand { get; set; }

    public LoginVM()
    {
        SavedLogins = new ObservableCollection<LoginData>(LoginDataManager.GetLoginDataList());

        UpdateSavedLogin();
        RemoveSavedLoginCommand = new RelayCommand<LoginData>(
            (data) =>
            {
                LoginDataManager.RemoveLoginData(data);
                UpdateSavedLogin();
            },
            ()=>true
        );
    }

    private void UpdateSavedLogin()
    {
        SavedLogins.Clear();
        SavedLogins.AddRange(LoginDataManager.GetLoginDataList());
    }

}
```

And Here's the RelayCommand Implemention

```
public class RelayCommand<T>:ICommand
{
    private Action<T> _action { get; set; }

    private Func<bool> _canExecute { get; set; }


    public RelayCommand(Action<T> action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action((T)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The binding for the Command property of the Button is not properly. VM is one of the property of the current page, it is not an element. You can change it like this:

```
<Page x:Name="page"  ... />
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=page,Path=VM.RemoveSavedLoginCommand,Mode=OneWay}" ... />
```